# parse a json composed file with asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i would like to parse my json file .but i found a problem,when i get my json from an existing api,i would like to create a function that will parse my json and store in a LIST

```
   IRestResponse response = ctm(departTime, departure, arrival);
        JObject resultJSon = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine("Rows:" + resultJSon);
        JArray rows = (JArray)(resultJSon["rows"]);
        if (rows == null) return ret;
        Console.WriteLine("Rows:" + rows);
        foreach (var r in rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            JArray cells = (JArray)r["cell"];
            Voyage voyage = new Voyage();
            voyage.Arrival = new Ville();
            voyage.Arrival.Name = arrival;
            voyage.Depart = new Ville(0, departure);
            voyage.Company = new Company();
            voyage.Company.Name = "CTM";
            for (var i = 2; i < cells.Count; i++)
            {
                string tmp = (string)cells[i];
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    voyage.DepartTime = 
     DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " " + tmp.Split(" 
      ".ToCharArray())[0]);
                }
                else
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    //price
                    voyage.Price = Double.Parse(tmp);
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    voyage.Type = tmp;
                    if (tmp == null || tmp.Equals(""))
                    {
                        voyage.Type = "CONFORT";
                    }

                }
                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    string[] els = tmp.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
                    if (els.Length >= 2)
                    {
                        if (els[els.Length - 1].Equals("Lendemain"))
                        {
                            DateTime tmpD = new DateTime(date.Year, 
  date.Month, date.Day);
                            tmpD = tmpD.AddDays(1);
                            voyage.ArrivalTime = 
   DateTime.Parse(tmpD.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " " + els[0]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            voyage.ArrivalTime = 
  DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " " + els[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ret.Add(voyage);
        }
```

my json file is the following:

```
     {
  "page": "1",
  "total": 1,
  "records": "8",
  "rows": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "cell": [
            "0",
            "02802902922332019020501",
            "00:30",
            "245.0",
            "CONFORT",
            "08:30  "
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "cell": [
            "1",
            "02207207215022019020501",
            "02:30",
            "255.0",
            "CONFORT  PLUS",
            "11:30  "
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "cell": [
            "2",
            "01300200208312019020601",
            "08:30",
            "250.0",
            "CONFORT  PLUS",
            "17:15  "
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "cell": [
            "3",
            "02239639609012019020601",
            "11:30",
            "250.0",
            "CONFORT  PLUS",
            "20:30  "
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "cell": [
            "4",
            "02200200213002019020601",
            "13:00",
            "245.0",
            "",
            "21:30  "
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "cell": [
            "5",
            "01300200221322019020601",
            "21:30",
            "250.0",
            "CONFORT  PLUS",
            "05:35  Lendemain"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "cell": [
            "6",
            "02702902920312019020601",
            "22:30",
            "245.0",
            "CONFORT",
            "06:15  Lendemain"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "cell": [
            "7",
            "01300200223032019020601",
            "23:00",
            "290.0",
            "PREMIUM",
            "06:15  Lendemain"
        ]
    }
   ]
   }
```

My Time of List is Voyage and here is the class:

```
   public class Voyage
{

    public Voyage()
    {
    }
    public Ville Arrival { get; set; }
    public Ville Depart { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartTime { get; set; }
 }
```

please if you could help me to find where is the problem

My Problem is solved .the problem was here :

```
   voyage.Price=Double.Parse(tmp);
```

i couldn't parse my String.
here how it is done :

```
  voyage.Price = double.Parse(tmp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i get []  it means i get an empty List

Comment: i don't get any error , but instead i don't get any data

Comment: You mean you are fretting empty list in `rows`? Did you debug the code? Foreach and for loops are executing properly?

Comment: i debug the code but didn't get any errors.how should i know if foreach or for loops are executing properly ?

Comment: i get this exception Exception levée : 'System.FormatException' dans mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Newtonsoft for JSON serialization and deserialization (Can be found in NuGet packages). With Newtonsoft, you are able to serialize into strongly-typed objects and vice versa. In this case, your code would look a little something like this:

```
var responseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Voyage>(response.Content);
```

The responseObj will contain all of the deserialized information and the "Row" objects will contain the deeper details in the "cell" property.

As for Voyage, the class would look something like this

```
public class Row
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> cell { get; set; }
}

public class Voyage
{
    public string page { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string records { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```